# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in Laravel?

Tags: arrays, laravel, query-builder

I tried filtering data based on the 'Jadwal_kuliah' and 'khs' tables but I found an error "The object of the class stdClass could not be converted to string" :

```php
function jadwal_kuliah_json()
{
    $nim = Auth::guard('mahasiswa')->user()->nim;

    $tahun_akademik = \DB::table('tahun_akademik')->where('status', 'y')->first();

    $kelas = \DB::table('khs')
        ->select('kode_kelas')
        ->where('nim', $nim)
        ->get();

    $jadwal = \DB::table('jadwal_kuliah')
        ->join('khs', 'jadwal_kuliah.kode_mk', '=', 'khs.kode_mk')
        ->where('jadwal_kuliah.kode_kelas', $kelas)
        ->where('khs.nim', $nim)
        ->select('matakuliah.nama_mk', 'jadwal_kuliah.hari', 'jam_kuliah.jam', 'ruangan.nama_ruangan', 'dosen.nama', 'kelas.nama_kelas')
        ->get();

    return Datatables::of($jadwal)->make(true);
}
```

JSON

```
{
    "id": 36,
    "kode_kelas": "TI18A",
    "hari": "senin",
    "kode_mk": "TI001",
    "nidn": "15110185",
    "jam": "1",
    "kode_jurusan": "ifd3",
    "kode_ruangan": "LBKom",
    "kode_tahun_akademik": "20182",
    "semester": 1,
    "created_at": "2019-02-28 15:02:52",
    "updated_at": "2019-02-28 15:02:52"
}
```

What needs to be changed?

Comment: Can you share the full and exact error message, and the line causing it?

Comment: $kelas is an object, it must be changed to a string, but if the class is changed to first() then only 1 data is displayed

Comment: Well, then "change" it to a string if you think that is the way to go. I'd recommend to use some kind of ID or whatever you store in the database to join these tables - but still, what's the problem in doing it?

Comment: I don't know what queries to use to filter data. if you use a condition where it must call one of the other conditions

Comment: What do you mean by "call one of the other conditions"? Why not use a scalar value like an ID? As we don't know anything about the structure of your models and tables, it's hard to help

Comment: check the update in my post. I added JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$kelas` is a collection and you're passing it as a string condition in :

```
->where('jadwal_kuliah.kode_kelas',$kelas)
```

First return an object using `first()` like :

```
$kelas = \DB::table('khs')
          ->select('kode_kelas')
          ->where('nim',$nim)
          ->first();
```

Then you must get the property instead like :

```
->where('jadwal_kuliah.kode_kelas',$kelas->kode_kelas)
```

Comment: how to change to string?

Comment: I have tried and an error appears "Property [kode_kelas] does not exist on this collection instance." because $kelas must use first(). I tried first() but only display 1 data

Comment: Yes, it will return one object,  else if you want a collection then how you'll handle multiple `kode_kelas` in `->where('jadwal_kuliah.kode_kelas', multiple_kode_kelas )` ?

Comment: You're performing a where clause like `select ... from .... where x=y` when the `x` is `jadwal_kuliah.kode_kelas` and the `y` is `kode_kelas`, now if you have a collection in `$kelas` then you'll ended up with different `kode_kelas` in every object of the collection, so you can't do anymore the `... where x=y` query, you need to think about `... where x in (list of y)`